# If $f$ and $g$ be such that $f(x)=0 \implies g(x)=0$, then $g(x)=\lambda f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations, solution-verification

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $f$ and $g$ be two non zero functionals defined on $V$ such that $f(x)=0 \implies g(x)=0$ for all $x \in V$. Show that $g= \lambda f$ for some $\lambda \in F$.

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$ $f,g :V \to F$ are both linear mappings and $dim(F)=1$ over $F$. Thereby, $0\leq dim(Im(f,g)) \leq 1$. Now, $f$ and $g$ both being non zero functionals, $dim(Im(f,g))=1$.

Now, $dim (Ker f)+dim (Im f)=dim V \implies dim(Ker f)=dim V-1$. Same goes for $g$.

Let  $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ be such a basis of $V$ that for only $x_1$ (say), $f(x_1) \neq 0$ and $g(x_1) \neq 0$ [ We can find such a basis by extending the basis of kernel of $f$ to a basis of $V$].

Let $f(x_1)=p$ and $g(x_1)=q$. Then, for  $p^{-1}q= \lambda \in F$, $q=\lambda p$.

Now, $\lambda f(x_1)=g(x_1)$. Hence, $\forall x= c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n \in V$, $g(x)=c_1g(x_1)=\lambda c_1 f(x_1)=\lambda f(x)$.

Hence $g= \lambda f$.

Is this proof correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: It _is_ true that you can find a basis $x_1,\ldots x_n$ such that $f(x_1) \neq 0 $ and $f(x_i)=0 $ for $i>1$. It is, however, _not_ true that if $x_1,\ldots x_n$ is a basis such that $f(x_1)\neq 0 $ then if follows that $f(x_i)=0 $ for $i>1$. I'm under the impression that you are using the second (incorrect) claim. If you are using the first one you should give a proof. In addition you should provide a reason why that particular basis will then have the same property for $f$. If you can show this the rest of the proof is easy.

Comment: @Thomas I have claimed that $f(x_1) \neq 0$ without any loss of generality. Now the second claim is I think justified (I might be wrong) since the dimension of the kernel is $dim V-1$.

Comment: No, that is not correct, which is exactly what I tried to point out. To see this is incorrect consider the standard basis $e_1, e_2$ of Euclidean $2-$ space and $f(ae_1 + b e_2) = a$, the orthogonal projection onto the one dimensional subspace spanned by $e_1$. Then consider the basis $x_1 = e_1+ e_2, x_2 = e_1 - e_2$.  You will note that $f$ is nonzero for both basis vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: @Thomas, I think I get it now. Taking an arbitrary basis for $V$ will not ensure that $\{x_i\}_{i>1}$ is a basis of $ker f$.

Comment: @Thomas : We can find a basis $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ such that $f(x_1)=p \neq 0, f(x_i)=0 , i>1$. By hypothesis, $g(x_i)=0, i>1$ and $g(x_1)=q \neq 0$ since $g$ is a non zero linear functional. Put $\lambda =qp^{-1}$. Now, $g(x_1)=\lambda f(x_1) \implies g(x)= g(c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n)=c_1g(x_1)=c_1 \lambda f(x_1)= \lambda f(x)$. 

Is this okay ?

Comment: that's the right approach, I did not check the details. But you have to say why you can find such a basis. The easiest way to do this is to note that the kernel of $f$ is a vector space of dimension $n-1$, so you can find a basis for it. Then there is a theorem which tells you that you can always extend a basis for a subspace to a basis of the whole space. For this extension you then know that $f$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: @Thomas, I argued the same way in the main post (using the extension theorem). Thank you for taking a look  :)